# App crashing randomly in iOS 9 iPad only - VKMapCameraController

Tags: ipad, crash, maps, ios9, xcode7

We are are getting a large number of crashes in our iOS app. It crashes only on iPad iOs 9 devices. Something related with maps. Logs from crashlytics are not helpful. We were unable to reproduce but there is spike un  Any guidance is appreciated.

__86-[VKMapCameraController _animateToPosition:pitch:yaw:duration:timingCurve:completion:]_block_invoke + 1510

[image]

Comment: Getting random iPad maps crashes and logs look similar.

Comment: Even I have the same issue. Still trying to solve no luck

Comment: Could this be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782161/unrecognized-selector-ispitched-called ?

Comment: Same issue. Looks like only iOS 9 and bothering on iPad only... darn it.

Comment: I'm getting those crashes in iPhone on iOS 9, strangely not iPad. Quite mysterious... Any solution? [The link Guillaume suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091664/app-crashing-randomly-in-ios-9-ipad-only-vkmapcameracontroller#comment54411753_33091664) doesn't work... :(